# Using the logo on a product

Tags: youtube-api

I sell a product that works with an app that has YouTube.

Am I allowed to put the YouTube logo on the front of the package?

Am i allowed to put the logo on 2-3 places on the package?

Answer (score 0):

I'm no lawyer and I don't know the exact terms of their API license, but in general such things are not allowed or endorsed. You may use product X, but you're usually not allowed to use it in your ads (which a package could be considered to be as well) or anything like that.

Having something in the feature description like "Ability to export to YouTube." or something like that is probably acceptable, but adding the logo? Very unlikely to be allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Our official guidance regarding using the YouTube brand is at https://developers.google.com/youtube/branding

Comment: Yes, but it does talk specifically about packaging. it says: You do not need special approval to use the YouTube API or to promote API functionality in your application, but does not say anything about packaging. Is it allowed?